# Check the last digit of a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I was doing some basic linear search exercises (I've been coding for 2 months or so) with javascript and stumbled upon the following problem:
I get input from the user that goes to an array and the program tells in which position of the array the number they decided to retrieve is. I wanted to do something clean like "`I've retrieved the number 69 for you. It was on the 22nd position of the array of inputs you created.`"

So I wanted to check the last digit of the number and respond accordingly with X1st, X2nd and X3rd or Xth.
But I don't know how to check the last digit of the desired number. Should I convert it into a string and then check with the .pop() function?

I only accounted for 30 inputs. But I would like for it to work not depending on a set number of inputs.

```
let inputsArray = [];
let totalInputs;

do 
{
  totalInputs = Number(prompt("How many number do you want to input? (max. 30)"));
}
while(totalInputs >= 31 || totalInputs <= 0)

for(i = 0; i < totalInputs; i++) //Get the inputs from the user and add them into the inputsArray
{
  let input = Number(prompt("Type a number"));
  inputsArray.push(input);
}

let desiredNum = Number(prompt(`What number do you want to retrieve? (Select from ${inputsArray})`));
let validator = 0; 

  for(i = 0; i < inputsArray.length; i++) //Check on each index of the inputsArray for the number prompted
  {
    if(inputsArray[i] == desiredNum)
    {
      if (i + 1 == 1 || i + 1 == 21) //Tell the user which position in the array the prompted number was
      {
        alert(`I've retrieved the number ${desiredNum} for you. It was on the ${i+1}st position on the array of numbers you created.`);
        validator++;
      }
      else if (i + 1 == 2 || i + 1 == 22)
      {
        alert(`I've retrieved the number ${desiredNum} for you. It was on the ${i+1}nd position on the array of numbers you created.`);
        validator++;
      }
      else if (i + 1 == 3 || i + 1 == 23)
      {
        alert(`I've retrieved the number ${desiredNum} for you. It was on the ${i+1}rd position on the array of numbers you created.`);
        validator++;
      }
      else
      {
        alert(`I've retrieved the number ${desiredNum} for you. It was on the ${i+1}th position on the array of numbers you created.`);
        validator++;
      }
    }
  }
  
  if(validator != 1) //If the desiredNum is invalid
  {
    alert("The number you specified does not exist in the array.");
  }
```

Comment: Convert the number to a string and then use `string.indexOf()` to find the position of the desired number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to convert to string. Let's just address what we are looking for with the number. The case is either 0, 1, 2, or other; the +1 you use is not necessary for computing this.

You can use `%` (modulo) here in order to check what the last digit is. Ensure that it avoids the edge case of 12nd with an extra condition.

This will allow for a single response to be issued instead of looking at multiple cases.

```js
var desiredNum = 20;

var suffixes = ["st","nd","rd"];
var suffix = num => (num < 4 || num > 13) && suffixes[num%10] ? suffixes[num%10] : "th";

for(let i = 0; i < 56; i+=11)
console.log(`I've retrieved the number ${desiredNum} for you. It was on the ${(i+1)+suffix(i)} position on the array of numbers you created.`);
```

Answer (score 4):

What if you tried a modulo operator like

```
last_digit = number % 10;
```

Comment: This is way better than unnecessary conversions!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the easiest way would be just convert to string:

```
  var str_number = number.toString(); //converts number to string
  var last_char = str_number.slice(-1); //gets last character
  var last_digit = +(last_char); //convert last character to number
```